# Fontawesome 5 icon not showing in normal HTML and CSS file?

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I am making simple website and I want to put social media icons on it.
I went to Fontawsome to take the icons and they are not showing on my site.
Here is the HTML:

```
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css">
    </head>


    <div id="social-menu">
          <div class="social-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Here is CSS:

```
.social-menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
}
.social-menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.social-menu ul li .fa {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 50px;
    transition: .5s;
}
.social-menu ul li .fa:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Read this: [Get Started](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/get-started/)
You propably didn't link the stylesheet link.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css"> i did

Comment: ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">``` use that.
Let me know if that worked then I'll add that as an answer..
Can you accept my edit on your post too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed Font Awesome Package which can be done using this command - `npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

or use the CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case use first, use font awesome CDN if already use then replace your code to class **fa** replace to **fab** then show your icon correctly.

CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Code:

```
<div id="social-menu">
    <div class="social-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```